# NSNumber weirdo ....?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

for a day now I stare at the following routine and can't get my grips around it. I have a class such as:

MyClass.h

```
...
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSNumber *myNumber1;
    NSNumber *myNumber2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myNumber1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myNumber2;

@end
```

and the m-file

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@synthesize myNumber1, myNumber2; 
@implementation MyClass

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];

    NSLog(@"Retain Counts myNumber1: %d, myNumber2: %d", [myNumber1 retainCount], [myNumber2 retainCount]);

    myNumber1 = [NSNumber inbitWithint:10];
    myNumber2 = [NSNumber inbitWithint:2];

    NSLog(@"Retain Counts myNumber1: %d, myNumber2: %d", [myNumber1 retainCount], [myNumber2 retainCount]);

    return self;
}
...
```

I use this class as a globals container and instantiate it from every other class in my app using a

MyClass *myGlobals = [[MyClass alloc] init];

===>>> the weirdo >>>

Running the routine I have the following facinating console output:

```
Retain Counts (before) - myNumber1: 0, myNumber2: 0
Retain Counts (after)  - myNumber1: 1, myNumber2: 26
```

How can that be?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you change it to `self.myNumber# = ...` instead? This is not an answer but I'm interested in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your actual code, it shouldn't work at all, it should simply crash. If not, you should cut and paste your actual code.

However, a couple of things.

First, if you use an NSNumber as an ivar, like anything else, you must take ownership of it. If you plan to use a convenience constructor, you must either assign it using the property on self, or send it an explicit retain message.

Second, you typed something like initWithInt: here. If you are actually using that message, then you have never actually allocated the number in the first place. You must replace this with one of the following:

```
myNumber1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10]; // explicitly create the number
myNumber1 = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] retain]; // take ownership through retain
[self setMyNumber1:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]]; // use the property accessors to deal with ownership and the convenience constructor to create the number
```

However you choose to do it, you must at some point take ownership of the object.

Comment: however using [self ...] is not the recommended approach during the init phase. Doing so could trigger a notification causing listeners to take action against an object that is not completely initialized.

Comment: @Brad Goss: nothing should be observing an uninitialized object in the first place. If something is, then the application has race issues regardless.

Comment: I agree with your comments, but your answer does not explain the issue asked about.

Answer (score 3):

## Do not call `retainCount`

The return value of `retainCount` can only be considered accurate if you are calling it on an instance of a class you wrote and you have *never ever not even once passed said instance to **any** API provided by the system.*

The absolute retain count is an implementation detail for which you might not have any control.

Assuming, for the moment, that your code was typed and, thus, the errors are not really in your original code...

NSNumber caches a subset of common values.  That is, for some numeric values, there is a single instance of NSNumber that is returned for all requests to retrieve an NSNumber instance wrapping that number.

Answer (score 2):

You should never even look at `retainCount` as it carries little significance anyway. The reason you see the count of 26 is that probably somewhere in the frameworks (or even in your own app) other instances of `NSNumber` exist that are created with the same `int 2`. An `NSNumber` is immutable, and so as an optimization `NSNumber` probably just gives you back an instance it has created earlier. As long as you don't look at `retainCount` it doesn't matter to you.